# what is the difference between a collection singleton or instance within Titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

In the Alloy docs, it mentions you can have a singleton or instance of a collection. You define one way or another using the instance tag:

```
<Alloy>
    <Collection id="localLibrary" src="book" instance="true"/>
    <Window>
        <TableView id="table" />
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

I understand the general idea behind a singleton vs instance... but I do not understand the direct advantage/application of exposing it one way or another to the controller.

Specifically, what is the difference between this controller code:

```
var library = Alloy.Collections.book;
library.fetch();
```

and this controller code:

```
var library = $.localLibrary;
library.fetch();
```

Is it saying "grab all" instead of "grab just this one?"

Any clarification would be great, tia.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that `Alloy.Collections.instance("book")` will create a global singleton instance (Or returns an existing...) which means that you will be able to access it in all your controllers using `Alloy.Collections.book`. You can do the exactly same thing with `Models`.

Why would you do this? I think it is quite useful if you can access and manipulate with a data that are already loaded for instance in a TableView in the first window while you are somewhere in a sub window...

**Globally Accessible Singleton:**

```
var library = Alloy.Collections.book; // <Collection src="book"/>
    library.fetch();
```

**Local Instance:**

```
var library = $.localLibrary; // <Collection id="localLibrary" src="book" instance="true"/>
    library.fetch();
```